# Probability, Random process, queue theory

Tags: probability, self-study

If you we have a bank that accepts at most 3 customers to be active simultaneously. The duration of a customer taken is a random variable with exponential distribution rate 1 customer/min, and customers arrive with exponential distribution rate 2 customer/min?

- The probability of the incoming customer is not accepted. " Means that the bank already has 3 customers active at the time when this customer came".
- If two customers at the bank, what the probability the next customer arrives before one of the two customer finish.
- If one customer is in the bank, find the probability that at least 2 new customers arrive before this customer leave.

for the first one I found result 11/8
Second one